# Find the flaw - Sum of two subspaces is a subset of their union

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Here is a flawed proof for $V+W\subseteq V\cup W,$ where $V$ and $W$ are subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^n$:

Consider $\mathbf{x}\in\left(V\cup W\right)^\perp.$ This implies:

$$\left.\begin{cases}\lt\mathbf{x},\mathbf{a}\gt = 0 & \forall\ \mathbf{a}\in V\\\quad\quad\quad\quad\mathrm{and}&\\\lt\mathbf{x},\mathbf{b}\gt = 0 & \forall\ \mathbf{b}\in W\end{cases}\right\}\Rightarrow \lt\mathbf{x},\mathbf{c}\gt = 0\quad\forall\ \mathbf{c}\in V+W\Rightarrow \mathbf{x}\in\left(V+W\right)^\perp.$$

Thus, $\left(V\cup W\right)^\perp\subseteq\left(V+W\right)^\perp\Rightarrow \left(\left(V+W\right)^\perp\right)^\perp\subseteq\left(\left(V\cup W\right)^\perp\right)^\perp\Rightarrow V+W\subseteq V\cup W.$

Can you spot the flaw(s)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that $V\cup W$ is not necessarily a subspace, so we may have that $((V\cup W)^{\perp})^{\perp}\neq V\cup W$. Indeed, $((V\cup W)^{\perp})^{\perp}=V+W$.